# How do I make a Google Fusion Tables map that displays only data from the latest date?

Tags: javascript, google-fusion-tables

Here is a [link](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1BNdNj9u3x0dzNVhq_Y0qPG8vtQxPuF6N_IQX9XM) to my Fusion Table.

If you look at the column labeled 'date', you can see two dates: 7/4/2012 and 7/5/2012. To the left is the column 'price', which changes depending on the date.

The map I am making is Geocoded according to the four U.S. Census Regions: Northeast, Midwest, South, and West.

I'd like to make a map that displays the price of the latest date.

So, in this case, clicking any Northeast state would show that 'price' is '0'.

Does anyone know how I can make this happen?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the [google visualization library](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference).  On click query the table for the region, order by date, limit 1 extract the price and display it.

[Here](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_GViz_infowindows.html) is an example that uses a gviz query to put data in the infowindows.

[This example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_GViz_infowindows3.html) might be more useful, it puts all the rows returned in an infowindow and allows the row to be dynamically selected, that part doesn't seem to work in IE8, but you don't need to dynamically change the data, since you only want the latest value.

[Here is an example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_GViz_infowindows_latestDate.html) which does what I think you want using your data.